# Automatically update online/offline member status using asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, offline, member, status

I use a table (lets call it T_User) with fields that describe each user. One of these fields is "Status" , a field that is updates to true every time the user logins (or if he is already logged in when he connects to my website) on my website and is automatically updated to false when the user leaves the page (no matter is the user logs out or not ). 
A solution for this issue i came up with is using Quartz.net to create a scheduler that will check all the session_id's of the online users to determine if the session is alive or not ! My problem is that i cant find a valid way to determine if the session is alive ! So how do I take the status of the session for each user ? Is there a better way achieving this "function" ? 
thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar for a project. I used [`SignalR`](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to see how many current connections was on my web app.

Example:

**HUB**

```
[HubName("trackingHub")]
public class TrackingHub : Hub
{
    public void SendCount()
    {   // Send the ConnectedUsers count to the caller
        Clients.All.count(SignalRConnectionHandler.ConnectedUsers.Count);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        // When a user connects, add him to the HashSet
        SignalRConnectionHandler.ConnectedUsers.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        SendCount();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        // When a user disconnects, remove him to the Hashset
        SignalRConnectionHandler.ConnectedUsers.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        SendCount();
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        // When a user reconnects, Check if he is already in the Hashset, if not add him back in.
        if (!SignalRConnectionHandler.ConnectedUsers.Contains(Context.ConnectionId))
        {
            SignalRConnectionHandler.ConnectedUsers.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        }

        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
```

**Connection Handler**

```
public static class SignalRConnectionHandler
{
    public static HashSet<string> ConnectedUsers = new HashSet<string>();
}
```

**View**

```
 $(function () {
        var hub = $.connection.trackingHub; 

        hub.client.count = function(count) {
            $('#count').html(count); // Append the connected users count to the page
        }

        // Connect the user to the Hub
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            console.log("connected");

        });
    });
```

If you add the `hub.start()` in your `_layout`. The `ConnectedUsers` hash will now contain all connected userId's. Since we can override some of the methods on the `Hub` we can set the `ConnectedUsers` when someone connects and disconnects.

As you can see I am storing everything in a `HashSet<T>` but you can store it in the DB etc. (Please note, storing it in memory like above, once IIS Recycles then the object will be lost)

Comment: is there an other way without using SignalR as i cant really configure how to make this work ...

Comment: Not really without reliable results. How are you going to know if a client has disconnected? What is your problem. I might be able to help.